# How can I fix this error 'ORA-01843: not a valid month'

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a table using the followning query:

```
create table customer1
(
custmer_id number, 
Customer_name varchar(20), 
Expiry_date  date default TO_DATE ('31-12-2009','dd-mon-RR')
)
```

the result is the following error :

```
Error report -
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Anyone to give me a light regarding this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong format mask. Neither is `12 = mon` (it is `mm`), nor is `2009 = RR` (it is `RRRR`).

Switch to

```
create table customer1
(
custmer_id number, 
Customer_name varchar(20), 
Expiry_date  date default TO_DATE ('31-12-2009','dd-mm-RRRR')
)
```

Comment: Or DATE literal, i.e `DATE '2009-12-31'` or `TO_DATE ('31-12-2009','dd-mm-YYYY')` - I prefer `RR` only for two digits but since I am working with computers for more than 18 years actually I don't use `RR` at all :-)

Answer (score 2):

**[TL;DR]** Use a date literal:

```
CREATE TABLE customer1 (
  custmer_id    NUMBER, 
  Customer_name VARCHAR2(20), 
  Expiry_date   DATE        DEFAULT DATE '2009-12-31'
)
```

or the `MM` format model:

```
CREATE TABLE customer1 (
  custmer_id    NUMBER, 
  Customer_name VARCHAR2(20), 
  Expiry_date   DATE        DEFAULT TO_DATE ('31-12-2009','DD-MM-RRRR')
)
```

---

From Oracle's [Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924):

- `MM`: Month (01-12; January = 01).
- `MON`: Abbreviated name of month.
- `MONTH`: Name of month, padded with blanks to display width of the widest name of month in the date language used for this element.

Oracle's [String-to-Date Conversion Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref478) allow additional formatting rules (without any other modifiers being applied). So:

- `MM` also matches `MON` and `MONTH`;
- `MON` matches `MONTH` (and vice versa);
- `RR` matches `RRRR`; and
- The punctuation is optional.

The format model `dd-mon-RR` you are using can match any of (with or without the hyphens):

- `31-dec-09`
- `31-december-09`
- `31-dec-2009`
- `31-december-2009`

But the `MON` format model does not also match the `MM` format so cannot match your string.

Instead, you should use the `DD-MM-RR` (or `DD-MM-RRRR`) format model which could match (again, with or without hyphens):

- `31-12-09`
- `31-dec-09`
- `31-december-09`
- `31-12-2009`
- `31-dec-2009`
- `31-december-2009`

If you want to only match a single date format then either:

- Use a date literal `DATE '2009-12-31'` (which only uses the ISO-8601 date format so skips the issue of your input not matching the format model); or
- Use the "format exact" `FX` format model modifier `TO_DATE( '31-12-2009', 'FXDD-MM-RRRR' )` which will prevent the String-to-Date conversion rules being applied and require the input to exactly match the format model.